# Changing the size and color of points in a scatter plot using a slider in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors, slider, scatter-plot

I am attempting to use a slider to change both the size and color of several points in a 3d scatter plot. I am confused as to why the colors will not update, and I havn't been able to find a command to update the sizes.

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib import pyplot
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider

def on_change(val):
    time=int(val)/1
    point1.set_color(col[time][0])
    point2.set_color(col[time][1])
    #point1.size(sizes[time][0])
    #point2.size(sizes[time][1])
    fig.canvas.draw()

x=[[.3,.7],[.3,.7],[.3,.7]]
y=[[0.5,0.5],[0.5,0.5],[0.5,0.5]]
z=[[0.5,0.5],[0.5,0.5],[0.5,0.5]]
p=0
col=[['blue','red'],['green','green'],['red','blue']]
sizes=[[100,10],[55,55],[10,100]]
fig = pyplot.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.plot([0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0],[0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1],[0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0],c='black',zorder=10)
point1=ax.scatter(x[p][0],y[p][0],z[p][0],s=sizes[p][0],color=col[p][0],zorder=0)
point2=ax.scatter(x[p][1],y[p][1],z[p][1],s=sizes[p][1],color=col[p][1],zorder=0)
ax.set_xlabel('Width')
ax.set_ylabel('Depth')
ax.set_zlabel('Height')
slider_ax = plt.axes([0.15, 0.05, 0.7, 0.02])
slider = Slider(slider_ax, "min", 0, 2, valinit=1, color='blue')
slider.on_changed(on_change)
pyplot.show()
```

Comment: just a guess: `point1` and `point2` might be undefined within the scope of your `on_change` function

Answer (score 0):

Sure not the most elegant nor correct way to accomplish what you ask, but until you figure it out you can reinitialize your Axes3DSubplot at every call of your function. In this case it as follows.

```
def on_change(val):
   time=int(val)/1   
   global ax
   ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
   ax.plot([0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0],[0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1],[0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0],c='black',zorder=10)

   p = 0
   ax.scatter(x[p][0],y[p][0],z[p][0],s=sizes[time][0],color=col[time][0],zorder=0)
   ax.scatter(x[p][1],y[p][1],z[p][1],s=sizes[time][1],color=col[time][1],zorder=0)

   fig.canvas.draw()
```

Comment: This helps, but is impractically slow running when the program is scaled up to more points. Is there anything that works like the .remove() method? [tried .remove() and nothing happened.]